# How to pass stored procedure name as parameter in DAL

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have more than one function which simply fetches data from DB. The difference among the function is the stored procedure name `(uspLoadStudents,uspLoadMarks)`. To optimize, make it as one function and passes the SP.

```
public DataSet LoadSubjects()
{
    string SqlDBConnection = Utils.GetConnectionString();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(SqlDBConnection);
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("uspLoadSubjects", sqlConn);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlConn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(sqlCmd.ExecuteReader());
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    sqlConn.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Do any of the stored procedures take parameters? If not, @FelipeOriani has the best solution, properly disposing of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information like sql command, stored procedure name, should be part of your `Data Access Layer`, instead it is a [helper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helper_class) inside the data access layer. Try this:

```
public static class DALHelper
{
    public static DataSet ExecuteProcedure(string procedureName)
    {
        string sqlDBConnection = Utils.GetConnectionString();    
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlDBConnection))
        {
            using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConn))
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();

                    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdpter(sqlCmd))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(ds);
                    }            
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Implement a method to use this helper, for sample:

```
public DataSet LoadSubjects()
{
   return DALHelper.ExecuteProcedure("uspLoadStudents");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I'm gonna try the same with SProcs along with parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
public DataSet ExecProc(string procName)
 {
     string SqlDBConnection = Utils.GetConnectionString();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(SqlDBConnection);
     SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(procName, sqlConn);
     sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     sqlConn.Open();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(sqlCmd.ExecuteReader());
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
     sqlConn.Close();
     return ds;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static DataSet getDataSet(string sp_name, string[] param_names, object[] param_values)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                sqlcmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmd.CommandText = sp_name;                        
                sqlda.SelectCommand = sqlcmd;
                sqlda.Fill(set);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                if (sqlcmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    sqlcmd.Connection.Close();
            }
            return set;
        }
```